# Framaroot is not a permanent root app

Tags: root-access

[framaroot](http://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/framaroot/root-framaroot-one-click-apk-to-root-t2130276) is not a permanent root method, what does it mean?

My phone is no longer receiving updates, so root won't cause problems I think

Comment: I haven't used Framaroot, but based on its FAQ on the same thread: "*Because framaroot exploit security holes present in several devices which has been patched with update you have done, so exploits can't root your device anymore. Framaroot's exploits have a very short life to keep your device "less exposed" to others malicious application.*" If the device is updated and the exploit is fixed, I'd *assume* that the root will fail, and thus, *not a permanent root*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could possibly mean that your device is rooted until the next reboot ie. temporarily rooted.
Also you can try another app/method of rooting which might be permanent so oyu don't have to root again.